# How to are Domain Events ignored from Migrations in Ardalis CleanArchitecture?

Tags: entity-framework, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

For references: https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture

The BaseEntity model contains a `List<BaseDomainEvents>`. This list is being ignored in when doing EF Migrations.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public List<BaseDomainEvent> Events = new List<BaseDomainEvent>();
}
```

How is this achieved? Nothing in the code indicates that it should be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a field, not a property, so it's ignored. EF only maps properties. Yes, since it's a field, it should probably be named `_events` instead of `Events`.